# Render plotly graph with reactive calculated values in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm simply trying to render a plotly graph with three bars: `gains`, `losses`, and `net`. `gains` and `losses` are controlled by `sliderInput`s, while `net` is calculated as the difference between `gains` and `losses`. I am not receiving any error currently, but the columns are not ordered properly and the column sizes are non-reactive, nor are the slider values being input into the columns properly, as can be seen by hovering over the column bars.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1("Title")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId= "gains", label = "Gains", min = 0, max = 10000, value = 3000, step = 1000),
      sliderInput(inputId = "losses", label = "Losses", min = 0, max = 10000, value = 4000, step = 1000),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Tab1",
          plotlyOutput(outputId="graph",height = "600px"))
        
      )
    )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  net <- reactive({get(input$gains) - get(input$losses)})
  
  new_data <- reactive({
    data <- c(get(input$gains),get(input$losses),get(net))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({ 
    graph <- plot_ly(
      x = c("Gains", "Losses", "Net"),
      y = ~new_data,
      type = "bar")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server =  server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `get()`. But to make your code work you could get rid of `get()` and define `new_data` like so:

```
new_data <- reactive({
    c(input$gains, input$losses, input$gains - input$losses)
  })
```

One more issue with you code is the way you call `new_data` inside `plot_ly`. Simply pass the new data like so: `y = new_data()`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1("Title")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId= "gains", label = "Gains", min = 0, max = 10000, value = 3000, step = 1000),
      sliderInput(inputId = "losses", label = "Losses", min = 0, max = 10000, value = 4000, step = 1000),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Tab1",
                           plotlyOutput(outputId="graph",height = "600px"))
                  
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
   new_data <- reactive({
    c(input$gains, input$losses, input$gains - input$losses)
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({ 
    graph <- plot_ly(
      x = c("Gains", "Losses", "Net"),
      y = new_data(),
      type = "bar")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server =  server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6643
```

[image]